# What is the notation for a system of simultaneous equations?

Tags: notation, systems-of-equations

Both in school and university, systems of simultaneous equations were denoted by a straight line in front of the equations (like a determinant, but no line after).

Now I find out that both LaTeX and all [google results](https://www.google.bg/search?q=system%20of%20equations&client=ubuntu&hs=fy4&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMImIzG9e2hyAIVAk4aCh23AAhJ&biw=1366&bih=642) look like this:

[image]

*What are the conventions?*

I live in Bulgaria, Europe. Here are a couple of examples from one book of analytic geometry, another, independent one uses the same notation.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always seen the notation
$$
\begin{cases}
&x_1 = 2r+s-t \\
&x_2 = r \\
&x_3 = -2s + 2t \\
&x_4 = s \\
&x_5 = t \\
\end{cases}
$$
I'm fairly sure this is standard notation, but you can of course adapt your notation as long as the reader understands (clarification might be needed).

Comment: Extremely weird. Maybe teachers have drawn them as a straight line for ease of drawing on the black/whiteboard. But no - I just checked a couple of books in linear algebra by different authors and straight line notation is used!

Comment: @Vorac Interesting. Like I said, it is entirely up to the author. The format for building systems of equations defaults to bracket notation in MathJax (and I think it is *generally* considered standard), but there are obviously some that prefer the line notation... what books, from which region? I'm somewhat curious now.

Comment: I edited those into my question. Sorry for the large images.

Comment: Discussing the issue with a friend, we arrived at the hypothesis that because our country has inherited most of it's standards and notations from Russia and Germany, they might significantly differ from western practices. Here is another example [page 2](http://www.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/algebra/lect_notes_ev/ran1.pdf).